# what does mobile mean in the expression?

Tags: meaning

what is mobile refer to in this sentence?

```
Mobile Clothes Hanger
```

is it mean the hanger that can be move?
can we use it without hanger. for example, we only say "mobile". I see it in a sentence that use it without hanger.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that it means a clothes hanger that can move. However, it would sound weird to use it by itself. Can you post the sentence that used mobile by itself?

Comment: yes, sentence is "make animal mobiles".

Comment: Ah! That's very different! There's a type of baby toy called a "mobile" which that's surely referring to. Here's what they look like: http://i.imgur.com/Rl9eZvu.jpg

Answer (score 1):

["**Mobile**"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mobile) here modifies "**clothes hanger**" and means "*able to be moved from one place to another*".

This is what a mobile clothes hanger is:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The phrase means

> mobile hanger for clothes

not

> a hanger for mobile clothes

meaning the hanger can be easily brought with you on  trip and probably fold into a very small form factor.